# Embedded Youtube API Freezes After Running Awhile in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, youtube, freeze

I created a comprehensive Youtube and CSS framework for video backgrounds which works great, autoplays, replays, and all that. But, after running for awhile it freezes and makes all the elements over it "drag" when I scroll (as in the pixels stretch over the Youtube player like the GPU just crashed). I tried to use: -webkit-transform:translateZ(0); to utilize CSS GPU acceleration by faking 3D. This **may have** helped but I can't be certain since the problem occurs sporadically. After refreshing the page, everything works fine again until I leave it running for a bit.

It could be my hardware, I'm running a 2012 Dell XPS with 8GB of RAM, i7 processor, 2 GHz with a Windows Experience index on my Gaming Graphics of 6.7, this problem only occurs in Chrome **as far as I know**.

Here is the code for the Youtube iFrame:

```
<iframe allowscriptaccess="always" style="z-index:-1000 !important;" id="videoBackground" onhover="return:false;" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/GI3rBwqwDbw?&version=3&enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer&allowscriptaccess=always&vq=hd1080&feature=player_embedded&autoplay=1&volume=0&controls=0&loop=1&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&wmode=transparent&rel=0&playlist=GI3rBwqwDbw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="false"></iframe>
```

and here is the CSS for the parent divs:

## overflowContainer {

```
background-color:#000;
width:100%;
height:580px;
overflow:hidden;
margin:auto;
text-align:center;
position:relative;
z-index:0;
-webkit-transform:translateZ(0);
```

}

## videoBackground {

```
position:absolute;
margin:auto;
left:0;
right:0;
top:-26.5%;
bottom:-26.5%;
width:1920px;
height:1080px;
z-index:0;
-webkit-transform:translateZ(0);
```

}

Let me know if you come up with anything or have any ideas to prevent this "crash".